# Connecting sqlserver to oracle Microsoft SQL Server error 7303

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle11g, database-administration

I have the following problem, I have a server with O.S. Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit, in this server I have installed a Database Microsoft Sql server 2014, and I'm trying to connect it to an Oracle Database 10.1.0.2.0 installed on an other server.

On my server I have installed a 64 bit Oracle Client 11.2, and 64 bit Oracle ODAC 11.2.

I tested my Oracle client installation connecting to my Oracle DB, using sqlplus, tnsping and configuring and testing 64 bit ODBC data source.

Now I have created a linked server to my Oracle DB, and I'm tryng to test it, but I have the following error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Connectioninfo
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDAORA"
>   for linked server ...
>
> OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server .... returned message
>   "It's impossible to find Oracle network components and Client...."
>   Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303.

What's the problem? Why SQL server doesn't find Oracle components and client, while it is installed on the server and useful?

Comment: is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a1a8dcbc-027c-4794-b13a-8bd4d7d4d682/problems-with-oraoledboracle?forum=sqldataaccess) it? >"Found the solution.... 'Allow inprocess' has to be checked in the provider options."

Comment: Oracle drivers are so awful. You may need to update the TSNAMES.ORA file too. It's always a struggle to use those native drivers.

Comment: My TNSNAMES.ORA is OK, cause my tnsping, sqlplus and odbc functs.

Comment: I have tried to unckeck allow in process on the Provider, cause it was checked and I have the problem and now I have a different error: Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" error 7302

Comment: MSDAORA is Microsoft provider. You have to use oracle provider - OraOLEDB.Oracle under the linked server - Providers. Microsoft no longer provide 64 bits providers for Oracle. May check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/07/31/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-oracle-and-linked-servers/

Comment: I don't find OraOLEDB.Oracle under the linked server Providers, but I have installed 64 bit Oracle Client 11.2, and 64 bit Oracle ODAC 11.2. Please let me know what I have to check

Comment: If I test my ODAC installation, creating a file test.udl and going to TAB provider on file properties I find Oracle provider for OLE Db. I don't understand why under sql server i don't find this provider...

Comment: I have a doubt, how can i check if my sql server is 32bit or 64 bit? Cause I'm sure that oracle client and oracle odac are 64 bit but now i'm not so sure about sql server

Comment: I used this query SELECT @@VERSION and obtain this result Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86) 
 Feb 20 2014 19:20:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor). So if i'm not wrong my SQL server is 32 bit, if it is so i can solve my problem installing 32 bit Oracle Client and ODAC? I'm trying I'll inform you

Comment: Solved the problem was that my Sql server is 32 bit version and doesn't see 64 bit Oracle client, installing 32 bit Oracle client and ODAC, it had seen the oracle ole db driver. Thanks for your precious collaboration